# Android - NumberPicker stuck on 0

Tags: java, android, numberpicker

I'm trying to set a NumberPicker that goes from "1" to seven , and to achieve that I have this layout:

> activity_reserva.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.trustinghelp.thelp.Reserva">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/duration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hola, es una prueba de si funciona"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2" />

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/hour"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/duration"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="368dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="121dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.435"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.45"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this code:

> reserva.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;

public class Reserva extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NumberPicker hour;
    //private NumberPicker minute;
    private final String[] minutes = new String[]{"0","30"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reserva);

        final String[] hours = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"};
        hour = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.hour) ;


        //Choose betwwen 1 and 7 hours
        hour.setDisplayedValues(hours);
        hour.setMinValue(0);
        hour.setMaxValue(6);
        hour.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

    }
}
```

The problem is that, on run time, all I get is a NumberPicker stuck on 0 and I have no way to go up or down. I have tried different approaches,like setEnable(true) or starting on "0" to see if maybe values was not a right String[]. No matter what I've trued, all I can ever get is a NumberPicker that's stuck on 0.

Am I forgetting anything?

Thank you very much!

Comment: try to set number picker value hour.setValue(1)

Comment: I still get a numberpicker set to 0 that will not move

Comment: Seems like an android bug. NumberPicker doesn't move, it bounces at the same number unless the control has focus.

Comment: @nurettin what do you with "unless the control has focus" ? Thanks!

Comment: @Álvaro I tried a few things, then I just gave up on setWrapSelectorWheel(false);